# iPhone - handleOpenURL Custom-URL-scheme plugin - not redirecting back to the application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, single-sign-on, cordova-plugins

I have an app written with AngularJS 1.5.3, Cordova, and Ionic v1.

I'm using these 2 plugins to implement some SSO (Single-Sign-On) functionality.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.10.3 (C:\Users\User\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.5
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.22

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.1.0, ios 6.1.0, browser 5.0.4, windows 4.4.3
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 17 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\User\Documents\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.21.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.14.4
   OS                : Windows 10
```

config.xml

```
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^4.0.0">
        <variable name="usewkwebview" value="true" />
    </plugin>
    
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme.git">
        <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="selfserviceapp" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="ANDROID_HOST" value=" " />
        <variable name="ANDROID_PATHPREFIX" value="/" />
    </plugin>

As I'm using cordova-ios 6.1.0 I'm using WkWebView only.

<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.1.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": "git+https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme.git",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-save-image": "^0.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-settings-hook": "^0.2.7",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.12",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "natives": "^1.1.6"
  },


    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-settings-hook": {},
      "cordova-plugin-save-image": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "selfserviceapp",
        "ANDROID_SCHEME": " ",
        "ANDROID_HOST": " ",
        "ANDROID_PATHPREFIX": "/"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {
        "usewkwebview": "true"
      }
    }
```

The app will open the Identity provider in a browser, the user will log in there, and then the user will be re-directed back to the application.

It's working perfectly on Android but for iOS it does not redirect back to the application.

It stays on the browser page and the user has to manually click the 'done' button to redirect back to the application.

*-Info.plist

[image]

[image]

code snippet:

on window object

```
var handleOpenURL = null;

window['handleOpenURL'] = function (url) {

    if (handleOpenURL) {
        handleOpenURL(url);
    }

};


        self.openUrl = function (url) {

            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                try {

                    SafariViewController.isAvailable(function (available) {
                        if (available) {

                            self.hideSpinner();

                            handleOpenURL = function (url) {

                                if (url.startsWith(ClientConfig.config.redirect_uri)) {
                                    self.processAuthCodeResponse(url)
                                        .then(function (token) {
                                            resolve(token);
                                        })
                                        .catch(function(error) {
                                            reject(error);
                                        })
                                        .finally(function() {
                                            window['SafariViewController'].hide();
                                        });
                                }
                            }

                            SafariViewController.show({
                                url: url
                            })

                        } else {
                            alert(' Browser Not Available! ');
                        }

                    });

                }
                catch (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }

            });

        };
```

Comment: have figured out how to solve it please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think thats not supported on Ionic v1, you can try firebase deeplinks to make your url redirect back to your app.